# RP2040- Memory architecture

Tags: spi, pi-pico, micropython

I am designing an RP2040 board that has external access to the QSPI chip. I need to be able to program the microcontroller externally without USB, and I thought this would be the easiest method. I'm not sure though how the NOR flash is structured. I looked at the documentation but I'm still confused. I may be on the wrong track here, so is there a better way to program the RP2040? I was planning on using micropython since I have more experience in it, but I'm open to using C/C++ as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can program the RP2040 internal RAM and external NOR flash using Serial Debug Wire (SWD). See section *2.3.4. Debug* in the [RP2040 datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A64%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C115%2C186.854%2Cnull%5D) for an overview of SWD. [Here's](https://www.electronicshub.org/programming-raspberry-pi-pico-with-swd/) a tutorial on programming the RP2040 using SWD.